# Sequelize error - "TypeError: hooks.concat is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Sequelize version: 4.38.0

In my node.js web application. 
I write model spec and run npm test.
at the `Create a model with associated data using set()` unit test.
but I get the following error:

```js
TypeError: hooks.concat is not a function
      at Function.runHooks (node_modules/sequelize/lib/hooks.js:102:23)
      at Promise.try.then (node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:3624:33)
      at tryCatcher (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
      at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
      at Promise._settlePromise (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
      at Promise._settlePromise0 (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
      at Promise._settlePromises (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
      at Async._drainQueue (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
      at Async._drainQueues (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
      at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
```

the following is my unit test code :

```js
it('Create a model with associated data using set()', async () => {
      // TODO:
      // 1. create a User and use set() method to set 1 associated model data.
      // 2. use model.findOne() with include to get model data with associated data.
      // 3. use data as Passport data, use `fakeData.create3` as user data.
      const data = {
        token: '1',
        workspaceName: 'ws1',
        passwordHash: 'ws1ws1ws1',
        provider: 'local',
      };

      let user = await models[SPEC_MODEL_NAME].create({
        ...fakeData.create3,
        Passports: data
      }, {
        include: [models.Passport]
      });

      const passport = await models.Passport.create(data);
      await user.setPassports(passport);

      const userWithPassport = await models[SPEC_MODEL_NAME].findOne(
        {
          where: {
            nickName: fakeData.create3.nickName
          },
          include: [models.Passport],

        }
      );

      expect(userWithPassport.nickName).to.be.equal(fakeData.create3.nickName);
      expect(userWithPassport.email).to.be.equal(fakeData.create3.email);
      expect(userWithPassport.Passports.length).to.equal(1);
      expect(userWithPassport.Passports[0].token).to.equal(data.token);
      expect(userWithPassport.Passports[0].workspaceName).to.equal(data.workspaceName);
      expect(userWithPassport.Passports[0].passwordHash).to.equal(data.passwordHash);
    });
  });
```

the following is my user model:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    nickName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
  });

  User.associate = function (models) {
    User.hasMany(models.UserOrder);
    User.hasMany(models.Passport);
  };
  return User;
};
```

the following is my passport model:

```js
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const crypto = require('crypto');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Passport = sequelize.define('Passport', {
    provider: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    token: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    workspaceName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  });

  Passport.associate = function (models) {
    Passport.belongsTo(models.User);
  };

  Passport.options.classMethod = {
    hashPassword: async (passport) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      await new Promise((defer, reject) => {
        if (passport.passwordHash) {
          bcrypt.hash(passport.passwordHash, 10, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            passport.passwordHash = hash;
            defer();
          });
        }
        defer();
      });
    },
    async createDefaultLocalProviderIfNotExist (user) {
      try {
        const localPassport = await Passport.findOne({
          where: {
            provider: 'local',
            userId: user.id,
          },
        });
        console.log('localPassport ==', localPassport);
        if (localPassport == null) {
          const newLocalPassport = {
            provider: 'local',
            password: 'password',
            userId: user.id,
          };
          console.log('=== newLocalPassport ===', newLocalPassport);
          await Passport.create(newLocalPassport);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        throw e;
      }
    },
  };

  Passport.options.instanceMethod = {
    async validatePassword (password) {
      try {
        const that = this;
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        let result = await new Promise((defer, reject) => {
          if (password === that.password) {
            defer(true);
          }
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          bcrypt.compare(password, that.password, (err, result) => {
            if (err) defer(false);
            else defer(result);
          });
        });
        if (result) return result;
        console.log('=== this.salt ===', that.salt);
        console.log('=== this.salt ===', result);
        if (!this.salt) return result;
        console.log('=== check two ===');
        const comparePassword = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, Buffer.from(this.salt, 'base64'), 10000, 64).toString('base64');
        if (comparePassword === that.password) {
          result = true;
        }
        return result;
      } catch (e) {
        throw e;
      }
    },
  };

  Passport.options.hooks = {
    async beforeCreate (passport) {
      return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          await Passport.hashPassword(passport);
          return resolve(passport);
        } catch (e) {
          return reject(e);
        }
      });
    },
    async beforeUpdate (passport) {
      return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          await Passport.hashPassword(passport);
          return resolve(passport);
        } catch (e) {
          return reject(e);
        }
      });
    },
  };
  return Passport;
};
```

the following is my userOrder model:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const UserOrder = sequelize.define('UserOrder', {
    price: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    count: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    subTotal: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    remark: DataTypes.STRING,
  });

  UserOrder.associate = function (models) {
    UserOrder.belongsTo(models.User);
    UserOrder.belongsTo(models.GroupOrder);
    UserOrder.belongsTo(models.Food);
  };
  return UserOrder;
};
```

thanks!

Comment: Can you share model definition for `Passport` and `UserOrder`?

Comment: @m1ch4ls I update that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking around at examples from the docs and looking into the source a little, I think Sequelize likes you to pass the full options object at the moment you call `define`. Create an options object for the `Passport` model, and assign the hooks to it before passing it as a second parameter to the `define` call (instead of modifying the options post-define). This will allow it to properly inspect that options object while initializing the model.